# pgsql numeric/decimal binary representation & Cocoa

Tags: postgresql, cocoa, libpq

I'm trying to add support for numeric/decimal pgsql (but also SQL99 standard) data type to a cocoa framework.
So far i haven't been able to find anything about the internal binary representation libpq is using when presenting its output for queries like

```
SELECT "12,345"::numeric(5,3);
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you *need* to know the internal binary representation? You generally exchange `numeric` value with the PostgreSQL server as formatted text, unless you explicitly request binary mode.

Comment: Thank you, Craig. Your information has saved me a lot of time digging in the the pgsql source tree. 
Regarding the question about using text vs. binary mode, i can say that the framework i'm contributing to uses binary mode by default.
I know, it would be much easier to work in text mode, since, in a way or another, i'm forced to build a string out of the binary representation in order to create a NSDecimalNumer (via decimalNumberWithString method), but, as i've said, i'm not in the position to change the framework's default behavior's details.

Comment: Sounds like `libpqtypes` will be ideal for you then.

Comment: @Creig
Right, Creig. I've given a lok at the projects: quite a good job.
But if i adopt your library i should dismiss djthorpe's postgresql-kit which, afaik, is the only stuff around encapsulating libpq in a cocoa framework.
Adopting your library would be fine but that would mean a rewrite from scratch for such a framework.
Anyway, who nows? May be i'll end up discovering that rewriting everything from start with your library would be time-saving if compared with extending the djthorpe's framework.
Thanks again, anyway.

Comment: It's not "my" library in any sense; I'm just familiar with it and know it's somewhat well liked. You could just as well borrow appropriate parts of `libpqtypes` code (if the license permits and do long as you retain the copyright information and give credit), then incorporate it into your project or into `postgresql-kit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary reference for the binary format is the source code - [`src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/backend_2utils_2adt_2numeric_8c_source.html). See [`numeric_send`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/backend_2utils_2adt_2numeric_8c.html#a57a8f8ab552bae24926d252180956958) and [`numeric_recv`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/backend_2utils_2adt_2numeric_8c.html#a3ae98a87bbc2d0dfc9cbe3d5845e0035) and the comments at the top of the source file.

Why do you *need* to work with the binary representation? You generally exchange `numeric` value with the PostgreSQL server as formatted text, unless you explicitly request binary mode.

If you do need the binary format you may wish to look at [`libpqtypes`](http://libpqtypes.esilo.com/browse_source.html?file=numerics.c), which contains support for the binary representation of `NUMERIC` and exchanging it with the server. You might want to consider using `libpqtypes` in your code. Perhaps submit a patch to add support for the arbitrary precision decimal floating point library you're using to `libpqtypes`.

See related:

- [libpq binary transfer of the numeric data type](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/491DC5F3D279CD4EB4B157DDD62237F404E27FE9@zipwire.esri.com)
- ... and [the reply from Tom](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16572.1091489720@sss.pgh.pa.us)

It's under-documented and it'd be nice to have this in the proper SGML documentation. Your patch will be welcomed ;-)